# how to filter anchor tags that were received from the jquery .each() function

Tags: jquery, filter, anchor, each

I have a div that contains allot of anchor tags.

Some of them have a img as the in side of the tag.

I need to get all of the "a" that have regular text in them not a image tag or any other HTML tag.

How can this be done with jquery.

To get them all i just do:

```
$(element).find('a').each(function () {
 ...........
});
```

But how do i filter them using the `.text()` function or any thing else.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector) and [`has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector) selectors

```
$(element).find('a').filter(':not(:has(*))').each(function() {

});
```

That says "find `a` elements, then filter that selection down to those that don't have child elements". `:has(*)` means "select elements that have any child elements", so `:not(:has(*))` means "select elements that don't have any child elements".

---

You can combine the two selectors:

```
$(element).find('a:not(:has(*))').each...
```

However, this means that `querySelectorAll` won't work, so the selection will be considerably slower.

[Live example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ekemes/edit#javascript,html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter the matched set of elements to contain only those with text:

```
$("#example").find('a').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).each(function() {
    //Do stuff
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/SVz2c/2/).

A slight problem with the above may be the fact that `$(this).text()` will evaluate to `true` if there is any text node present within the `a` element. That includes a single empty space. To prevent that, you may want to trim the text:

```
$.trim($(this).text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this **simple and easy**

```
$(element).find('a').not(":has('img')").each(function () {
 ...........
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An idea: in the each block make the check this way:

```
$(element).find('a').each(function () {
if($(this).text() == $(this).html())
{
...........
}

});
```